# Hide menu items in Wordpress

Tags: php

I want to remove menu items depending on the URL in Wordpress with PHP. The following code has been put into the child themes functions.php.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 65535, 3 );

function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args ) 
{
    if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

    //Select what not to be shown
    //$item->title = "" is assigned for these menu items
    //if anything is to be removed $bremove == 1

    if ( $bremove == 1 )
    {
        $bloop = 1;
        while ( $bloop == 1 )
        {
            $bloop = 0;

            $items = array_values ( $items );

            foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) 
            {
                if ( $item->title == "" )
                {
                    unset ( $items [ $key ] );
                    $bloop = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

The code works by first setting the unwanted titles to nothing and then erasing them with unset. I have tried many ways of unsetting, but none works. Above is a try with array_values and restarting the loop upon anything is removed.

What ever I do some wanted menu items disappear. Just setting the titles to nothing works perfectly, but then a blank is just shown.

I have noticed that just unsetting, doesn't reindex the array. Sidebar menus work great, but not the main menu.

How should the erasing of menu items be done?